# Get shortcut key failed with "Alt + num" in PretranslateMsg in MFC?

Tags: mfc

I want to preprocess the keyboard message in PretranslateMsg in MFC. So I write the following code.

```
 if( pMsg->message == WM_KEYUP )   
        {
            if( GetKeyState(VK_CONTROL) || GetKeyState(VK_SHIFT) || GetKeyState(VK_MENU) )
            {
                CString csKey = TranslateKeyToString( GetKeyState(VK_CONTROL) & 0x8000 ,GetKeyState(VK_SHIFT) & 0x8000, GetKeyState(VK_MENU)&0x8000, pMsg->wParam );
                DoWorkForAcceleratorKey(csKey);
                return TRUE;
            }
        }
```

With above code. I can successfull get shotcut in "csKey" for "Ctrl+Alt+1" and "Ctrl+1" but I can't Get "Alt+1", when I press Alt+1, the csKey is a strange single character. 
So what happens for the "Alt+1", And how to solve this problem? 
Thank you.

Comment: Put a break point inside TranslateKeyToString and check its arguments.

Comment: `Alt+<key>` are a bit special because typically they are used to navigate the main menu, so you may find they are being filtered out even before they get to `PreTranslateMsg`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't get a WM_KEYUP message for the <kbd>1</kbd>. 
With the <kbd>Alt</kbd> key, the entered characters are used in a different way.

Instead of a WM_KEYUP, you receive the WM_SYSKEYUP. The WM_KEYUP you receive should have the nVirtKey code of VK_MENU.

This is are the messages captured by Spy++ when I press <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd> in Notepad.

```
WM_SYSKEYDOWN nVirtKey:VK_MENU cRepeat:1 ScanCode:38 fExtended:0 fAltDown:1 fRepeat:0 fUp:0
WM_SYSKEYDOWN nVirtKey:VK_MENU cRepeat:1 ScanCode:38 fExtended:0 fAltDown:1 fRepeat:1 fUp:0
WM_SYSKEYDOWN nVirtKey:'1' cRepeat:1 ScanCode:02 fExtended:0 fAltDown:1 fRepeat:0 fUp:0
WM_SYSCHAR chCharCode:'49' (49) cRepeat:1 ScanCode:02 fExtended:0 fAltDown:1 fRepeat:0 fUp:0
WM_SYSKEYUP nVirtKey:'1' cRepeat:1 ScanCode:02 fExtended:0 fAltDown:1 fRepeat:1 fUp:1
WM_KEYUP nVirtKey:VK_MENU cRepeat:1 ScanCode:38 fExtended:0 fAltDown:0 fRepeat:1 fUp:1
WM_SYSKEYDOWN nVirtKey:VK_MENU cRepeat:1 ScanCode:38 fExtended:0 fAltDown:1 fRepeat:0 fUp:0
```